# How can I solve this error and install cocoapods?

Tags: swift, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

In my terminal I use:

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

My terminal gives the error shown below. How can I solve this? I have tried a few variations and I cannot get it to work.

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200518-1427-ajbhbt.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: You need to install Xcode's developer tools. The easiest way to do this is through terminal . 

> xcode-select --install

Comment: I believe @VinayakaSY is correct. I have also added Ruby to your tags to get more specific feedback from them as well.

Comment: I did xcode-select--install but terminal gives command not found.

Comment: `xcode-select --install`, note the space.

Comment: I downloaded that software successfully and then try download cocoapods again. This time terminal gives that `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to install Xcode's developer tools. The easiest way to do this is through terminal .

```
xcode-select --install
```

Later,  if there are any write permission issues, use the below code.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin/..
```

P.S: `-n` specifies the directory where binaries are located.

Comment: If you have to use `sudo` to install a gem, you’re already in trouble. You need to get control of your ruby installation and not depend on Apple for this.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Vinayaka and Bryan you're missing some ruby header files and it looks like they're required. Not sure about your environment setup but it may help to just reinstall the latest Xcode from scratch.

Also, I've had some recent problems with Cocoapods installed via terminal. The terminal installs the latest build of Cocoapods. If you're looking for something stable then maybe try the Cocoapods app. It's clunky and it can't read pod files from the latest version of Cocoapods **(so you'll have to regenerate any existing podfiles)** but its easier to work with especially for those who prefer a graphical environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved just now with @VinayakaSY answer. I added sudo gem install cocoapods usr/bin.... with path and it is working.

Comment: Great answer Rajat! Welcome to SO and thanks a lot for already providing people with excellent, clear answers. Good luck in your journeys.

Answer (score -1):

Please try with
**brew install cocoapods**